# Efficiency sending images as base64 string to Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I intend to upload an image together with name and email as a single transaction to a Firebase Cloud Function using HTTP POST. The Function will write details to Firestore database and store the image in Firebase Storage.

I thought about using Firebase Storage browser client API but because it's only a small avatar image and I want to keep client code thin (i.e GUI code only), I opted to use Cloud Function as a sole interface between my app and the backend.

If I send the image as a base64 encoded string, would there be any size limit to the payload and would there be any practical downside such as potential for timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

> would there be any size limit to the payload

The payload size limit for Cloud Functions is 10MB and can't be exceeded.

> would there be any practical downside such as potential for timeouts

There's always a chance for an HTTP request to fail due to a timeout or other network disturbance.  If you want to work around that, you will need to implement some retry logic in your app.